# MySQL: Optimizing queries

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

How can I write this in a more optimized way?

```
SELECT week_day
     , SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) 
     / (SELECT SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3)
             FROM Hotel.RegIn) * 100 AS MIN_PERCENTAGE
  FROM Hotel.RegIn 
 WHERE week_day = "Wednesday" 
 GROUP 
    BY week_day;
```

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say 2), you can be confident that your schema design is sub-optimal

Comment: Do you have to use single select expression?

Comment: @Nae not really I was just looking for another way to write the query perhaps a more optimized way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it as below:

```
SELECT
    "Wednesday",
     100 * SUM((week_day = "Wednesday") * (min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3))
        / SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) AS MIN_PERCENTAGE
 FROM Hotel.RegIn
;
```

or if you can use multiple statements, another one with easier filters:

```
SET @var_all_day_total :=
    (SELECT SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) FROM Hotel.RegIn) / 100;

SELECT
    week_day,
    SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) / @var_all_day_total AS MIN_PERCENTAGE
FROM Hotel.RegIn
-- WHERE week_day = "Wednesday"
GROUP BY
    week_day
;
```

The idea usually is not to redundantly calculate the same values more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You should use derived table in the `FROM` clause. This way the subquery will be evaluated only once.

```
SELECT 
  week_day,
  SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) / RegInSum.sum_all * 100 AS MIN_PERCENTAGE 
FROM
  Hotel.RegIn,
  (SELECT 
    SUM(min_0 + min_1 + min_2 + min_3) as sum_all 
  FROM
    Hotel.RegIn) as RegInSum 
WHERE week_day = "Wednesday" 
GROUP BY week_day;
```

Note that as far as you restrict your query only to one day of week, you won't get any performance gain by rewriting the query, because the subquery will be evaluated only once in both cases.

See [CTE (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) for more readable syntax of derived tables in newer versions of MySQL.

Comment: so you mean to say that both are the same in terms of query optimization?

Comment: @tootiefairy Yes, I think if you definitely know you will use your query only for Wednesday (or for a single arbitrary day of a week, specified in a parameter for example), you don't have to optimize your original query.